# Regular Expressions in R: str_extract_all

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I need help with Regular Expressions in R.

```
library(stringr)
text <- "Detailed Description, {type:status-update,activityText:Closed,date:2018-06-01T12:00:15+0200,status:Closed}, {type:status-update,activityText:Inprogress,date:2018-06-01T12:00:15+0200,status:Inprogress}, Responsible:ABC"

str_extract_all(text, "status-update.a")
```

The result is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "status-update,a" "status-update,a"
```

In this same manner I type the following code

```
str_extract_all(text, "status-update[[:print:]]+}")
```

To get the following: this means the following is my expected output

```
[[1]]
[1] "type:status-update,activityText:Closed,date:2018-06- 
01T12:00:15+0200,status:Closed" "type:status- 
update,activityText:Inprogress,date:2018-06- 
01T12:00:15+0200,status:Inprogress"
```

simply I want extract the bits that are in the curly brackets but I get the error below:

```
Error in stri_extract_all_regex(string, pattern, simplify = simplify,  : 
Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curly brackets are part of the regular express syntax thus if you want to extract them, place the escape character in front.

```
str_extract_all(text, "\\{.+?\\}")
#[[1]]
#[1] "{type:status-update,activityText:Closed,date:2018-06-01T12:00:15+0200,status:Closed}"        
#[2] "{type:status-update,activityText:Inprogress,date:2018-06-01T12:00:15+0200,status:Inprogress}"
```

To only capture the text within the {}, one needs to use the regular expression's look behind and look head options.

```
 str_extract_all(text, "(?<=(\\{)).+?(?=\\})")
```

What the pattern means:

```
(?<=   ) Look behind this match
\\{  look for the left curly bracket   
 .+   with at least 1 character (any character)      
 ?    do not perform a greedy match (without it will grab everything)    
\\}  to the right curly bracket
(?=   ) look head of match
```

Comment: What if I wanted to extract the strings without the curly brackets at the beginning and at the end in specific to this example? In general, when I declare the pattern in str_extract_all, how can I impose that what I want to get is actually without the left and right boundaries?

Comment: @lara, see the edit which include look behind and look ahead.